# Understanding 'rather do we'

Tags: conjunctions, translation, literary-techniques

I came across a peculiar sentence structure today:

> Rather do we do A; but B.

I think this is an archaic grammatica structure. What is the meaning of the above structure?

The full phrase is given below:

> [We must not evade darkness.] Rather do we freely acknowledge that what remains after the entire abolition of will is for all those who are still full of will *certainly nothing*; but, conversely, world, which is so real, with all its suns and milky ways—is nothing.

(I also don't understand how the italicized part fits into the sentence. Any help will be greatly appreciated!)

Answer (score 3):

The text is from a translation of Schopenhauer. There are commas after "is" and "will", and you have omitted some words. From the translation at bartleby.com:

Rather do we freely acknowledge that what remains after the entire abolition of will is, for all those who are still full of will, certainly nothing; but, conversely, to those in whom the will has turned and has denied itself, this our world, which is so real, with all its suns and Milky Ways — is nothing.

The phrase "for all those who are still full of will" is parenthetical.

I'd paraphrase "Rather do we" as "Rather, we" or "On the contrary, we".

Comment: Thank you, I read this from Russell's History of Western Philosophy but for some reason the comma is missing there. I undertstand how 'certainly nothing' fits in. Then does the sentence roughly mean: 'If we abolish will, what remains is nothing. If conversely, the will denies itself, the universe is nothing.'?

Comment: This is inversion after an adverb/ial. Nowadays, this is usually limited to negative adverbials (Seldom had he felt so happy / Never would it be bettered / Hardly had he spoken ... / No sooner had he left ... / ...). 'Rather' is an antiparallel statement connector (like 'on the contrary'), so has a negative pull. But archaic/literary usage allows inversion after almost all adverbials (though 'on the contrary' seems an exception):  ('Simbelmynë. Ever has it grown on the tombs of my forebears.' Theoden; LOTR).